# pow() function gives wrong result

Tags: python, modulo, exponential, bignum, wolframalpha

I want to execute this math function:

```
3^(3^1000000000) mod 1000000007
```

the result of this is: `930782551`

But do it directly in python takes a huge amount of time, and the program hangs:

```
return pow(3,pow(3,1000000000),1000000007)
```

So I thought that execute this will be the same:

```
return pow(3,pow(3,1000000000, 1000000007),1000000007)
```

but the result is: `270196661`

How can I get the correct result `930782551` in a reasonable time?

Comment: Your WA expression should've been `(3^((3^1000000000)mod1000000007))mod1000000007`. What you've put there and what you put here aren't the same.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: You need Fermat's Little theorem / Euler's theorem to do this efficiently. Fortunately, 1000000007 is prime so it's easy to calculate the totient function for it.

Comment: @PM2Ring I asked a question on math.stackexchange to figure out how to compute this. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: The question is a very good one, I suggest an edit putting the original pow function that takes a huge amount of time, and ask how to make it in a reasonable time

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, the question is a really good one, an a valid one, the accepted answer as you can see, put people to think and work, so I think giving a second chance maybe is a good idea this time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edit in your question, use

```
>>> pow(3, pow(3, 1000000000, 500000003), 1000000007)
930782551
```

Anything else will take forever to compute. This expression was obtained using Fermat's little theorem.

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2317797/454045) on math.stackexchange.com. Bottom line, `pow` does not print the incorrect result. It is absolutely correct. Your input was wrong.

Comment: Once I'd verified that 1000000007 is prime I just did `pow(3, pow(3,1000000000, 1000000006), 1000000007)`

Comment: I didn't know about Fermat's theorem so I had to ask a question. x)

Comment: Fermat's Little theorem is a beautiful piece of number theory, and it's not too hard to understand. And once you have that down, it's not too hard to prove Euler's theorem. And when you have _that_, you can understand how RSA encryption works.

Comment: this is brilliant !

Comment: @PM2Ring Yep. I've got a lot to learn. Also, I thought Euler's Theorem _was_ the proof for Fermat's?

Comment: Very beautiful work you did, just brilliant the idea of look up for help in another community and put all the pieces together... Just a perfect well done work, congratulations. I just thought the problem was a simple sintáxis problem, but I learned a lot with all of it. Is a plus one in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

> Edit

At first I thought it was an issue of sintaxis, so I answered:

```
return pow(3,pow(3,1000000000),1000000007)
```

But it takes an unreasonable amount of time. So I tried to solve the problem of the computing time, but I didn't do it in time :).

> The perfect answer is the @Coldspeed one, he could solve the computing time issue just great, the whole explain is there

Comment: Do you know how long that'd take to compute?

Comment: this will break

Comment: @Don'tcallme that's true, at the really beginning I just thought it was a sintáxis problem, but it was a lot more, I up voted the question because it was really interesting indeed, I hope you accept the edition

Comment: @Coldspeed you are right, at first I just think it was an issue of sintaxis, I will upgrade the answer